# multiple layouts in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have two layouts in my site one for the main site and one for the admin panel :

RootLayout:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning lang="en">
      <head />

      <body className="dark:bg-black">
        <Providers session={undefined}>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer />
          <ScrollToTop />
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

AdminLayout

```
export default function AdminLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <head />
      <body className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col ">
        <AdminProviders session={undefined}>
          <TopBar />
          <div className="flex space-x-1 ">
            <Sidebar />
            {children}
          </div>
        </AdminProviders>
      </body>
    </>
  );
}
```

they work fine but as soon as i go from the admin page back to the root page i get this error:

**Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

what seems to be the issue ?

Comment: I'd say the issue is: That you are providing the `<head />` and  `<body>` tags in the child layout. Child layouts do not need to include these tags. As seen [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts) in the official documentation.

Comment: How are you exposing these components?  I see nothing wrong with either of the code blocks you have shown.

Comment: i tried without the body and head it still doesnt work

Comment: Is this in Next 13's app directory? I think there's still some bugs around navigating away from routes.

Comment: yes its in next app directory, is there any fix or another way of doing multiple layout that might work?